# Hola me da este error en visual studio alguna solucion para esto?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]estoy haciendo un programa pero me sale este error en el c# pues quiero usar el switch case pero no logro que este funcione ya intente cambiar las variables definir una variable desde afuera y asi pero me sigue dando el mismo error.
Esta en aplicacion de consola de Visual Studio de igual manera se muy poco del lenguaje y de programacion en general.

Comment: Explica q es lo que quieres hacer, y edita tu pregunta y pon tu codigo como texto

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto formateado segun corresponda (si es un error como comentario, si es codigo como codigo),siempre.

Comment: Rodriguez alvarado podrias decir si las respuestas dadas te resultaron utiles, gracias

Answer (score 2):

**Estas haciendo un mal uso del `Switch`.**

El `Switch` se lo utiliza con el objetivo de dar a ejecutar tal acción correspondiente a un caso objetivo. Esto quiere decir que `Switch` tiene que recibir tu caso objetivo, no aplicar una validación.

`Switch` recibe un valor que es el que indica que caso quiere proceder a procesar. Entonces como estas haciendo una validación que el resultado es un booleano, pues `Switch` no puede asignarle a un caso en especifico porque el parámetro de entrada es el incorrecto.

**Esto te puede ayudar:**

Intenta asignarle un valor a `Switch` dependiendo de tu caso en especifico, como se muestra en la validación `if`, entonces con eso ya puedes asignarle un valor correspondiente a un caso del `Switch`

```
var salarionominal = (horasdetrabajo * pagoHoras);
var salarioextraordinario = 0.0;

var VarSwitch = 0;
if (Horasdetrabajoextras <= 10)
    VarSwitch = 1;

switch (VarSwitch) 
{
    case 1:
        Console.WriteLine(salarioextraordinario = horasdetrabajo * pagoHoras);
        break;
    default:
        Console.WriteLine("DEFAULT");
        break;
}
```

Comment: VAldria aclarar, que de ser asi, este codigo no tiene ningun sentido no?

Answer (score 0):

Eso te sucede porque en tu **condicional switch** estas usando un **operador relacional (<=)** que devuelve un **booleano** con dos posibles valores: **true** o **false**, y tu estas usando un valor entero en los **case** del **switch**, cuando deberías usar los valores **true** o **false**, por tanto tu código podría ser algo parecido a esto:

```
switch (HorasDeTrabajoExtra <= 10)
{
   case true:
       {
          Console.WriteLine("True");
          break;
       }
   case false:
       {
          Console.WriteLine("False");
          break;
       }
}
```

En dependencia de si la **expresión booleana** analizada en el **switch** retorna **true** o **false** se ejecuta el **case** correspondiente.

Si solo vas a manejar dos posibles estados como parece ser en tu ejemplo pues seria mejor que utilizaras el **condicional if**:

```
if(HorasDeTrabajoExtra <= 10)
{
   Console.WriteLine("True");
}
else
{
   Console.WriteLine("False");
}
```

Comment: Vuelvo a publicar mi respuesta pq parece que hubo alguien que escondiendose en el anonimato me dio un voto negativo, y como mi respuesta es correcta la vuelvo a publicar

Comment: Y esta mal... no es correcto que hagas eso... la verdad, esta respuesta sufre el mismo problema de la otra que esta, el codigo no tiene ningun sentido....

Comment: @gbianchi, pq no tiene sentido?

Comment: Porque escribiste un if, de la forma mas complicada que uno se pueda imaginar... no tiene sentido, como tampoco tiene sentido en la otra respuesta y se lo aclare...

Comment: Y esta muy pero muy mal que borres una respuesta y la dupliques solo porque alguien te dejo un voto negativo... just live with it.. como hacen todos....

Comment: @gbianchi, quien dice eso?, ese criterio se basa en tu opinion personal, el usuario quiere hacer un switch y yo le explique como funciona de forma correcta, mas nada

Comment: Y estas seguro que OP quiere hacer un switch, o realmente no sabe como funciona y para que sirve un switch y solo escribio el codigo como le parecio que debia ser? esa es tu opinion personal ;)

Comment: @gbianchi con mi explicacion ahora sabe como hacer un switch q maneje expresiones booleanas, el op acaba de aprender algo nuevo ;)

Comment: @gbianchi te acabo de complacer, espero estes de acuerdo ahora con lo nuevo que le puse a mi respuesta

Comment: ahora si, suena a una respuesta completa y logica, no te parece tambien?? en lugar de contestar secamente, le estamos enseñando en serio...

Comment: @gbianchi y tu no crees que en vez de que te den un voto negativo era mejor explicar eso y yo lo arreglaba, ya que a cualquiera se le va un gazapo, el voto negativo se da cuando hace falta, no hay q abusar de el, en lo particular yo apenas doy votos negativos(aunque los he dado), prefiero hacerle entender a la persona que existen mejores soluciones

Comment: yo no te vote negativo.. asi que no se porque te lo dieron... ninguna de las respuestas merecia un voto negativo.. si un comentario, de que no era logico... en tal caso, quejate con quien te lo dio.. pero no esta bueno borrar respuestas por eso...